# How to use CQRS in C or any other procedural language?

Tags: c, cqrs, procedural-programming

Citate from Wikipedia: "CQS is well-suited to the object-oriented methodology, but can also be applied outside of object-oriented programming. There is nothing inherently object-oriented about the separation of side effects and return values, and so CQS can be profitably applied to any programming paradigm that requires reasoning about side effects".

I need simple example of using CQRS pattern for creating modular program in non-OOP language.

That article in Wikipedia have some chunks of code, but not explain interaction between them.

Comment: Questions about concepts of programming are better asked at the http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

CQS has nothing to do with if a program is modular or not. It only specifies that a function that modifies a value should not return the value or if it returns a value it should not have modified it.

For example

```
int x;
int increment()
{
  x = x + 1;
  return x;
}
```

which increments a integer and returns the pointer to it would break CQS. Instead that should be two functions,

```
int x;
void increment() { x = x + 1; }
int value() { return x; }
```

Comment: You did not say anything that would complement a Wikipedia article.

Comment: I don't see there being much more to say, that is CQS.

Comment: Did I put this concept makes more sense than there originally was present. That's how I decided to do. I do not know what it's called, and whether it has a name at all. http://vadimtukaev.blogspot.ru/2014/03/define-arraylength-100-define.html

Comment: It doesn't have a formal name, but it definently isn't CQS... you have `get`-functions doing `set` and changing variables all over.

Comment: Wonderful, I will consider myself a genius who invented a new design pattern. ;)